# How Elimante Duplicate Data in multiple Array

Tags: arrays, duplicates, preg-match-all

Houston I have a Problem. I have this `preg_match_all` the response is many array with duplicate numbers (the original data has these duplicates). I need to eliminate duplicate numbers and transfer to one variable. I Try with `array_unique()` and `array_merge()`. Thx for your help.

```
preg_match_all('~x">([^"]*)<\/h4>|[0-9]{5}~',$preg_data,$item, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Output:

```
Array ( )
Array ([0] => x"> 13:30 - Denver</h4>   [1] =>  13:30 - Denver)
Array ( )
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69275))
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69275))
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69275))
Array ()
Array ([0] => x"> 16:00 - Miami</h4>[1] =>  16:00 - Miami)
Array ()
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69280))
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69280))
Array ([0] => 69275)Array([0] => Array([0] => 69275[1] => 69280))
```

if (@preg_match_all('/([0-9]{5})/',$item[0],$match, PREG_SET_ORDER)); {
print_r($match);}

```
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69268 [1] => 69268 )) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69268 [1] => 69268 ))
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 )) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 ))
Array ( )
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 )) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 ))
Array ( )
Array ( )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 )) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 69270 [1] => 69270 ))
Array ( )
```

Comment: Try `if (preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5}/',$item[0],$match)); { print_r(array_unique($match[0]));}`

Comment: No Working it the same result,

Comment: Can you update the question with the value of `$item[0]` and what the expected result is?

Comment: Yess, you clear my mind, I fix the problem. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this combinations

```
    preg_match_all('~x">([^"]*)<\/h4>|[0-9]{5}~',$preg_data,$data_mach);    
    $data_clean= array_values(array_filter(array_unique($data_mach[0])));
```

preg_mach to extrac data
array_unique to eliminate duplicates
array_filter to eliminate blank
array_values to work only numbers.
Done.